# Php inside wordpress pages stopped working after update

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and it runs with some php code inside the pages. After I updated it stopped working and when I try to edit the code again, it changes the <?php to <!--?php not allowing it to run anymore.

I tested with a simple code like:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World"
?>
```

And it's not working after the update.

Is there any easy solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: from where you are updating your code?

Comment: This can be down to the versions of PHP you're using on your site & thats supported by your hosting provider. For example, some PHP shorthand may not be supported in version 7. So on times your code will be commented out to prevent your website completely erroring out. Checkout what versions of PHP your hosting provider supports. Ideally you want 5 and up

Comment: I'm running the code from the Wordpress page editor itself @ArifulIslam

Comment: you can not write php code inside editor as this willl use escpate the string . that's why it will be converted to special character instead of php syntax

Comment: @idlab I was running the latest php version after the update. Now I rollbacked it to 5.6 and it's not working yet.

Comment: @ArifulIslam but I'm using the text editor, not the visual one. It used to work because my page was running okay.

Comment: If you're writing php inside the page editor it means you're using some plugin, by default you can't do it! Check your plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue using 2 plugins to insert php and javascript code into the page. Thanks a lot @idlab and @arifullslam for the help!